# Selecting count without Group By

Tags: sql-server

I have following table in `SQL Server 2005`. One order can have multiple containers. A container can be either Plastic or wood (New types may come in future).

I need to list the following columns -

```
OrderID, ContainerType, ContainerCOUNT and ContainerID.
```

Since I need to list the ContainerID also, the following group by approach won’t work.

```
DECLARE @OrderCoarntainers TABLE (OrderID INT, ContainerID INT, ContainerType VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @OrderCoarntainers VALUES (1,101,'Plastic')
INSERT INTO @OrderCoarntainers VALUES (1,102,'Wood')
INSERT INTO @OrderCoarntainers VALUES (1,103,'Wood')
INSERT INTO @OrderCoarntainers VALUES (2,104,'Plastic')

SELECT OrderID,ContainerType,COUNT(DISTINCT ContainerID) AS ContainerCOUNT
FROM @OrderCoarntainers
GROUP BY OrderID,ContainerType
```

What is the best way to achive this?

Note: Upgrading `SQL Server version` is not an option for me.

**Expected Result**

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use a [windowed function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
SELECT  OrderID,
        ContainerType,
        COUNT(ContainerID) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID, ContainerType) AS ContainerCOUNT,
        ContainerID
FROM    @OrderCoarntainers
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I will change the answer for you.

Comment: Hi, may I know how do I further add condition on the count result ContainerCOUNT?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know SQL Server dialect of SQL that well, but I can suggest something that is pretty basic and may work. It relies on a join, which is not optimal for performance but will get the job done if the table is not huge or performance is not critical. Really the problem here is the table design is pretty bad for the data you are managing, as this should not all be in one table. But anyway:

`SELECT o1.OrderID, o1.ContainerType, count(o2.ContainerID) AS ContainerCOUNT, o1.ContainerID
FROM @OrderCoarntainers o1 JOIN @OrderCoarntainers o2 
ON o1.OrderID = o2.orderID AND o1.ContainerType = o2.ContainerType
GROUP BY o1.OrderID`

Comment: I think @astander wins the day because he knows some SQL Server tricks I don't. +1 for his answer even if mine would work.